# Using "Until" to mention the aim of doing something

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

An English learner wrote:

> Next time I will try to make a plan till counteract her plot.

A native speaker didn't correct it, when he was revising the passage. (Maybe it was neglected).

I doubt if "till" can be used for mentioning the aim of something, similar to "to" or "in order to" or "so that". right?

In general, can "until" be used to convey the aim?

Comment: Next time I will try to make a plan until I counteract her plot. You need to notice that you need a sentence in this case after until. Otherwise you can use until+noun. ex. until completion. And I'm not comfy with your "till" but it's hard to explain why

Answer (score 2):

"to" would work: "a plan to counteract her plot".

Using "until" in place of "to" doesn't make sense at all to me as a native English speaker.